# Android -- image icon next to actionbar tabs, using Sherlock Library

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I am currently implementing ActionBarSherlock into my existing project.

I plan on using 3 tabs. I can get the Tabs working correctly, but I can't seem to figure out one problem.

I am targeting lower end phones since my app is quite friendly with many models of phones. However, using an action bar, a tabs layout, and then a viewpager within the tabs layout has its costs. The fragments seem rather small on my HTC Incredible test phone.

As a result, I decided to take out the action bar, and try to add an icon next to my "tabs".

With a TabView, I could of course next it inside a parent view and add an icon, but I am having trouble doing the same with actionbar (or specifically ActionBarSherlock)

I am of course, programmatically adding tabs using;

```
final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        ActionBar.Tab tab = getSupportActionBar().newTab();
        tab.setText("Tab " + i);
        tab.setTabListener(this);
        getSupportActionBar().addTab(tab);
}
```

Help or hints are greatly appreciated.

Thanks